# finding length of object in image

Tags: image, image-processing

As a part of our project we have to find the dimensions of a given object in a particular image ex- dimensions of a given sunken ship which is underwater. This is totally new to me so my friend told me that in matlab its possible. Kindly help me out

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into `image blobs` and `Edge detection`. That's where I would start

Are you already set on MatLab? If you can use C#, I would look into: AForge.NET Image processing library for C#:

http://www.aforgenet.com/projects/iplab/

I have used AForge before to identify "blobs" in images and perform other image processing operations.

Answer (score 0):

If you have still not finalized on Matlab, then AForge.NET or Magick.NET from ImageMagick can be tried. 
To identify the dimensions of the image, we have to think thru the manual process of identifying the same. How are we able to identify ship in water from an image? How is the object different from sorrounding area in the image?

From that, you may try to identify ship as a blob and work on the blob. Sometimes, you may not be able to identify ship as blob, probably due to noise of the sorrounding. Find means to remove that noise or differentiate the object further from sorrounding by errosion or dillation or combination.